# ScrollView "inside" Imagebutton

Tags: android, layout, constraints, imagebutton

im having some troubles to achieve this kind of design in an android app.

[image]

What i first have is a **ConstraintLayout** that inside have a **ImageButton** (wrapping his content). All ok.

But i want also a **HorizontalScreenView** that has the same width that **ImageButton** have and inside of him a large **ImageView** that start at the horizontal center of the **HorizontalScreenView**.

An **example** of the situation in code...

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/example"/>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="¿HERE IS THE PROBLEM?"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <!-- I WANT THIS IMAGE TO START AT THE CENTER OF PARENT (HorizontalScrollView) -->
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/example"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/example"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">


   <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- This image starts at the center of parent (HorizontalScrollView) -->
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/example"/>

   </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: But there the HorizontalScreenView has the ConstraintLayout (parent) size. I want it to have the Imagebutton width.